# Neo4J Readify client/driver: Unable to deserialize object

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Im getting a error/exception when im trying get a resultset by running the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<NeoProduct> GetAllProductsUnderCategory(int categoryId)
                 {
             var query = neo.Cypher.Match("(c:Category{CategoryId:{id}})<-[*](p:Product)")
    .WithParam("id", categoryId)
    .Return(p => p.As<NeoProduct>()).Results;
            }
```

As you can see its a very simple method that returns a list of NeoProducts. NeoProduct is a simple POCO with the following properties:

```
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
```

The stacktrace is:

```
   [OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.]
       System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +14278344
       System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider) +55
       System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +14285879
       Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.CoerceValue(DeserializationContext context, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, JToken value, IEnumerable`1 typeMappings, Int32 nestingLevel) in D:\temp\tmpC806\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CommonDeserializerMethods.cs:101
       Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.Map(DeserializationContext context, Object targetObject, JToken parentJsonToken, IEnumerable`1 typeMappings, Int32 nestingLevel) in D:\temp\tmpC806\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CommonDeserializerMethods.cs:365
       Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.CreateAndMap(DeserializationContext context, Type type, JToken element, IEnumerable`1 typeMappings, Int32 nestingLevel) in D:\temp\tmpC806\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CommonDeserializerMethods.cs:303
       Neo4jClient.Serialization.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<ParseInSingleColumnMode>b__1(JToken row) in D:\temp\tmpC806\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CypherJsonDeserializer.cs:437
       System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +223
       System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +264
       System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +106
       Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.Deserialize(String content) in D:\temp\tmpC806\Neo4jClient\Serialization\CypherJsonDeserializer.cs:64
   [ArgumentException: Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied.
```

For the method, I'm passing a argument which returns a result-set containing 900 entities (result is from the Neo4J browser). Otherwise, the method seems to be working as intended.

I suspect that the JSON object is too large for the internal deserializer. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Have you verified that the JSON object is too large? What happens if you return one product?

Comment: It was never the JSON object per see; the database contained dirty data. :)

Comment: I thought it might be - exception messages do not usually lie! Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 6):

I discovered the problem. There was a entity in the database which had a very long number which was larger than int64 causing the deserializer to throw a exception (was trying to insert a number larger than int64 into a int64 property).

Today's lesson: Make sure the data fit into the model :)